# Retrieving Millions of Records from oracle database

Tags: sql, google-app-engine, elasticsearch, solr, oracle11g

The problem Is related to dashboard creation .based on any filter there might be millions of record .they might be displayed in a table ,a graph ,some histogram like so ....

One approach i know for displaying table is paging .But if u need to display as histogram u need to store complete information ,after querying the filter .
Query might be itself too complex and it might have multiple join and in clause .
Can u provide a faster search engine ,other than sql such that data can be indexed and retrieval took fraction of seconds .

Comment: The problem is more about moving the million(s) of rows from your database, whether is oracle or something else, to your dashboard application. Your dashboard application then needs to receive, process and display the dashboard information. Try it with a table that just has 1M rows in and select them all; no complex query; just a single table select...

Comment: I think one should realize - there is no free lunch and you cannot simply juggle with millions of records in fraction of seconds :) But! Maybe actually what you are looking for is to represent your million of records in digestible and user-friendly format on single-page. I.e. like with facets / aggregations / histograms and so on. Is Kibana or Banana what you are looking for? You can ingest your data into elastic/solr and utilize their super-powerful features of filtering / faceting / aggregation.

Comment: Thanks #PaulVasilev  One problem is data is real time ?regular update are required .Can i use Kibana to display result in angularJs .